# javascript phonebook application- How do I return search results from a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, search, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am creating a 2D phonebook array using html forms and javascript

I am able to sort, add, delete records etc but I can't figure out how to return a record from a user search.

I have managed to return the index of the phonebook entry I want using several methods but I want the actual entry to display to the user.

Is this possible in javascript? I feel like it should be easy but I am stuck!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone book</title>
 <script>
 myPhonebook = Array (
Array(' Robert Mory ',' 07554035121 '),
Array(' Susie Thompson ',' 0785430270 '))

document.write("<pre>")
 for (j = 0 ; j < myPhonebook.length ; ++j)
 {
 for (k = 0 ; k < myPhonebook.length ; ++k)
 document.write(myPhonebook[j][k])
 document.write("<br />")
   }
   document.write("</pre>")

  var search = function(){

var searchInput = document.getElementById('inputIdSearch').value
document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = 
      ("Searching for: " + searchInput + "...")
document.writeln(myPhonebook.indexOf('searchInput'))



 </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <div id = "container">
  <h2>Phonebook 1.0</h2>
  <form name = "phonebookForm" id = "phonebookForm">
<h4 id ="search">Search Phonebook: <input type = "text" id="inputIdSearch" onblur="search()">
    <span id="searchResult"></span></h4>
  <h4 id ="input">Add entry: <input type = "text" id="inputIdInput"></h4>
  <h4 id ="view">View all entries: <input type = "text" id="inputIdView"></h4>
  </form>
        </div>
           </body>
              </html>
```

Comment: btw I just noticed a missing } at the end of the search function- just a c+p error

Comment: Also I know you can access individual elements using: alert(myPhonebook[1][1]); However I want to be able to show entries based on user input.